# How To Migrate Meteor-Blaze App to Meteor-React App [ Closed ]

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-blaze

My Meteor-Blze App running at version @1.2.

I want to completely migrate this Meteor-Blaze app into Meteor-React app with  latest running version.

How to do this?

Comment: blaze and react are front end developement. there are structures are entirly diffrent. possible way is manual migration.

Comment: Plus it will be harder, the tighter you have coupled your front end code with your backend code e.g. hard coded method calls, publications and so on within your templates.